# What does this warning symbol on my pannier bag mean?

Tags: safety, accessories, luggage

I bought a pannier bag which attaches to the rear rack with 3 quick-releases. Each quick-release has a sticker on it:

[image: strange hammer warning symbol]

What does this symbol mean? My guess would be something like "don't hit this with a hammer", but it seems rather unlikely that anyone would, so I'm really not sure what I'm being warned about.

Comment: If they need such stickers they have a usability problem.

Comment: It's because the bag mfgrs support the "Ban Hammers!" movement.

Comment: First thing I would remove! I hate dang stickers, especially stupid ones.

Comment: Likely 1 person some time hit it with a hammer or other tool trying to latch it, cracked the plastic, had the bag break open, and tried to sue. Like 90% of 'warning' stickers on products, its probably just there to prevent liability. You can tell it was an afterthought, since the sticker is too big for the latch its stuck to, so some lawyer probably made them stick it on there well after they engineered it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means "No tools" or "Use your hands."

Comment: Seems a pair of pliers would be more appropriate symbol for this particular case.

Comment: No using a screw driver.  Good luck!

Comment: "Do not use while hammered."